# call function inside function JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i have problem that I can't understand:

```
var Copyright =
{

    onLoad: function () {
        this.initCopyrightMoving();
    },


    initCopyrightMoving: function () {
        $(".sidebar_toggle").click(function () {
            var copyright = document.getElementById("copyright-text");

            if (copyright.className == "copyright-menu-open") {
                this.decrease(280, 80, 10, copyright);
            }

            else
                copyright.className = "copyright-menu-open"

        });
    },

    decrease: function (actual_val, stop_val, step, copyright) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (actual_val == stop_val) {
                copyright.className = "copyright-menu-closed";
            }
            actual_val = actual_val - step;
            copyright.style.paddingLeft = parseInt(actual_val) + "px";
            this.decrease(actual_val, stop_val, step, copyright);
        }, 10);
    }

};
```

and when I call `initCopyrightMoving` in line `this.decrease(280, 80, 10, copyright);`, I get this error:

```
copyright.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: this.decrease is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (copyright.js:14)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3)
```

can sm tell me what I did wrong? And also because I can't run next part of script can you tell me if `decrease` function is written good, I mean will it run properly.

Answer (score 0):

`this` here is element `$(".sidebar_toggle")` you clicked.

Try defining `var self = this;` before jQuery handler and call `self.decrease` inside handler

`this.decrease` inside `setTimeout` will also not work for similar reason. Fix is the same

Answer (score 0):

This is because `this` (context) changes when it's inside the `click` callback. One way you can stop the error is by preserving a copy of `this` and using that inside the callback.

```
initCopyrightMoving: function() {

  var _this = this; // some developers use `self`

  $(".sidebar_toggle").click(function() {
    var copyright = document.getElementById("copyright-text");
    if (copyright.className == "copyright-menu-open") {
      _this.decrease(280, 80, 10, copyright);
    } else {
      copyright.className = "copyright-menu-open"
    }
  });
},
```

[Here's a useful article](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/) on scope and context in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks,worked :)